# Parse Text In Twig View In ZF2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am designing the opening page of my personal web site.  I am trying to use the same service function as the 'blog' section opening which retrieves the latest blog entry.

However I only want up to the 2nd paragraph to display on the opening page of my person web site.  For me to re-use the service function I would need to parse after the second

```
</p>
```

within Twig.  In other words I would want something like

```
<p>blah1 blah1 blah1</p>

<p>blah2 blah2 blah2</p>
```

to be the result.  What syntax is needed in Twig?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you edit your post and make it clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this...

Let's say that your text content is inside a twig variable named **content**.

Split your text content on every occurrence of `</p>`:

```
  {% set contentArray = content|split('</p>') %}
```

First paragraph is everything inside first element of array after the first occurrence of `<p>`

```
{% set firstParagraphArray = contentArray[0]|split('<p>') %}
{% set firstParagraph = '<p>' ~ firstParagraphArray[1] ~ '</p>' %}
```

Second paragraph:

```
{% set secondParagraph = contentArray[1] ~ '</p>' %}
```

Output:

```
  {% autoescape %}
      {{ (firstParagraph ~ secondParagraph)|raw }}
  {% endautoescape %}
```

Alternatively, you could make twig extension, that does all this job, and makes twig code a little bit cleaner.